# Replace predictive failure in RAID 10 array

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid

We have 7 physical drives (6 RAID 10, 1 hot spare) attached to an LSI SAS2008 controller.

Recently a drive failed and the hot spare took over. When the new drive landed I just replaced the failed drive with the new one and that took over as the hot spare.

I then downloaded the LSI RAID Web Console 2 and noticed another 2 drives reporting a predictive failures. The book of words for the web console is for a different, older, version and hours of Google searches have not returned a definitive answer.

I am making an assumption that the correct procedure is to right click the drive in the console and select 'Make offline' - wait for it to spin down and replace it. If so will it start building to the hot spare again and the new drive takes over as hot spare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in every assumption, just do that, one disk at a time and check everything at the end, then you're done. Easy one but worth checking right.

Comment: Long time ago I was on the phone to MegaRAID and they talked me through a procedure - it wiped everything and I was not a happy bunny - so with a server that has to be up 24/7 and puts food on the table it's belt and braces. Marked as answer but it would appear that on this forum, unlike Stack Overflow, I can't vote it up. Thank you

Comment: No problem, we have a minimum rep limit thing, it's actually the same on SO but you obviously have enough rep, either way don't worry, I stopped worrying about rep a LOOONG time ago :)

Comment: Seems I can mark it up now (and did)! Ho, hum. Server 2008, 2016, 2019 and now I can mark it up :-) Where did  that six years go!

Comment: My six years turned into a lot of grey hairs and four degrees between my two kids :)

Comment: 'Nowt wrong with a bit of grey, lad!' as they would say in Yorkshire. Well done on bringing up two kids with degrees in this Bizarro world. Have noticed with the drives it's best to let them go until they fail totally, leave the controller to rebuild using the hot spare then replace the faulty drive. Seems less messy.

Comment: That sounds like a good tip, I'll try to remember it - I'm buried in the middle of giant Ceph farms now so long for the days of raid arrays :) Are you a Yorkshire lad/lass then? If so I'm originally from the other side of the Pennines, South Coast now though.

Comment: Born in Essex, brought up around Worthing, lived in North Yorkshire and now live in the States (west coast).

Comment: Very nice, we nearly moved to Worthing when we moved out of London, ended up in Christchurch.